# Set include paths of c/c++-project relative to workspace path in Visual Studio Code (.json configuration)

Tags: c++, c, json, visual-studio-code

I'd like to define the include paths of my [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)-project in [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode) relative to my workspace folder. As `mainfolder` has a different path on every system I work on, and I don't want to always change the configuration file.

I have the following folder strucure

```
mainfolder
   /include1
   /include2
   /project/workspacepathofVScode
```

So the folder I open with vscode is `workspacepathofVScode`.

In my configuration file `c_cpp_properties.json` I used `**/**/` to get from my workspace root two levels up, to include my two include folders, but it does not seem to be the correct syntax:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "**/**/include1",
                "**/**/include2",
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "**/**/include1",
                    "**/**/include2",
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

**How can I define the include paths relative to `workspacepathofVScode`?**
If it is not possible the way I thought, do you know any workaround?

Comment: I don't ever worked on this configuration file, but for a typical filesystem path, I would expect dot characters and not stars to produce relative paths `"../../include1"` - is the vscode property file special in this regard?

Comment: @grek40 That's what I try to find out. It's not documented anywhere. The dot notation does not work neither.

Comment: I came across [`${workspaceFolder}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) when I was doing somehow the same thing.

Comment: @AmirMaleki It is maybe a new feature. Feel free to post an answer, but I will need some time to test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vscode doesn't support relative paths directly, but it is possible to start with a path variable containing an absolute path and then append a relative path. See the following bug discussion: [Unable to resolve includes with relative paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/366)

So for the presented case of paths thats should be relative to the workspace path, start with the workspace path variable and use `".."` instead of `"**"` to navigate to parent folders.

The complete path for `include1` should be:

```
"${workspaceRoot}/../../include1"
```